# deleting a specific record from a binary file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binaryfiles

each record in binary files is stored like this

```
import pickle
student={}
def add():
    
    n=int(input("enter number of entries"))
    for i in range(n):
        name=input("enter names")
        marks=eval(input("enter marks"))
        student[name]=marks
    f=open("sample.dat","wb")
    pickle.dump(student,f)
    f.close()
```

if want to delete a specific record with name=<"some name"> how to do it

i tried like this but its  not correct

```
def delete():
    x=input("enter name to be deleted")
    for i in student:
        if x==i:
            del student[x]

        else:
            print("name not found")
```

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: no error as such

Comment: You say 'its not correct' - please be more specific. It cannot be incorrect if you don't specify exactly what it is supposed to do :)
What is the expected outcome? What is the actual outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, a couple of improvements

1. In your code you `del` an element of `student` while you iterate over it.
   This is an error, while iterating over a dictionary you should not modify its keys.
   For more information, read this:
   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-delete-items-from-dictionary-while-iterating/
2. You don't need to iterate over the dictionary at all. Dictionary keys are unique, so checking if `x` is in the dictionary is sufficient. You can do that with `if x in students:`.
3. Don't explicitely close file descriptors. Use **context managers** instead.
   Like here: https://cmdlinetips.com/2016/01/opening-a-file-in-python-using-with-statement/

For everything else, I have to guess, because your question is not specific enough.

---

I *guess* that you expect that when you call the `delete()` function that the file content changes. But the delete() function does not write to any file, so maybe you forgot saving the new `student` dictionary to the file?

Just a wild guess:

```
def delete():
    x=input("enter name to be deleted")
    if x in student:
        del student[x]
    else:
        print("name not found")

    with open("sample.dat","wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(student,f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not modify the contents of dictionary while iterating over it.

What you can do though is iterate over an array of keys of dictionary and delete items from dictionary if it matches.

i.e change your delete function to:

```
def delete():
x=input("enter name to be deleted")
for key in list(dict.keys(student)):
    if key==x:
        print('matched')
        del student[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pickle
def delete():
    f = open('bin.dat', 'rb+')
    n=int(input('Enter roll no. which you want to delete:'))
    i=[]
    v=[]
    flag=0
    try:
        while True:
            i = pickle.load(f)
            v.append(i)
            if i[0]==n:
                v.remove(i)
                print("successfully deleted!!!!!!")
                flag=1
    except Exception:
        if flag==0:
            print("record not found")
        f.close()
    with open("bin.dat",'wb') as g:
        for i in range(len(v)):
            pickle.dump(v[i],g)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).